# Inserting Mathematical Symbols into tinymce 4?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, math, tinymce, symbols, angular-ui

How can i use mathematical symbols in tinymce.
I am using angular ui for tinymce, normally it's working fine.
But i want to insert mathematical symbols. 
like

[image]

Is it possible.

Please help me. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I have developed some custom plugin solution:

Please take a look: https://github.com/Axel186/graphs-tinymce-plugin

With this plugin you will be able to put any Math content by using MathFont([MathJax](https://www.mathjax.org/))

If you are interested in some Graph editor, to build visual graphs/diagrams by using functions take a look at this: https://github.com/Axel186/graphs-tinymce-plugin

Those plugins are absolutely free and have a MIT license. Use it ;)

Answer (score 0):

There are two nice tinymce plugins that will let you insert mathematical formulaes into tinymce.

- [Tinymce-Plugin from codecogs](http://www.codecogs.com/latex/integration/tinymce/install.php)
- [Tinymce-Plugin from fmath](http://www.fmath.info/plugins/TinyMCE/demo.jsp)

Comment: This is working in normal html files, but i am using theses mathematical tinymce into my C# code, it was not working...... i am using UI-Tinymce

Comment: indeed, in that case you need something different

Answer (score -1):

There is two tinymce 4 compatible plugins using math quill is available at

- https://www.npmjs.com/package/tinymce_mobileequationeditor
- https://github.com/laughinghan/tinymce_mathquill_plugin

You can install them by placing the code in the tinymce plugins directory, adding the plugin to the plugin and toolbar configuration option like the following

```
tinymce.init({
  selector: 'textarea',
  plugins: 'mobileequationeditor',
  content_css: '/tinymce/plugins/mobileequationeditor/mathquill.css',
  toolbar: [
    'mobileequationeditor'
  ],
});`
```

Comment: Please summarize the article you linked. If the link changes, your answer will become useless.

Comment: If the link changes the software is not available and the answer becomes useless, for example @tharama answer has a broken link now.

Comment: If the link answer is an issue, I'd suggest down voting the other answers while your at it or having the question moved to software recommendations.